# oracle select date from partition table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Following statement allows me to retrieve information about a table's partitions:

```
select table_name, partition_name, high_value from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'T1';
```

problem is that, for some unknown reason, high_value column's values are expressed as:

```
TO_DATE(' 2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
```

is it possible to retrieve them as date? Or at least do something like "eval" on that expression?

Comment: `TO_DATE()` function returns a `DATE`. What is your problem?

Comment: to_date is the exact value of the column, I am getting it as a string...

Comment: Is this related to this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/31926904/409172

Answer (score 2):

That field is defined as a long type, so depending on the partitioning scheme, it can hold various values (a string like 'ABC', a number 123, a string representation of a date, whatever).

Anyway, sounds like you want to get data from a particular partition, and you're trying to figure out the partition name from the metadata.  If thats the case, you can simply use the partition for clause:

```
select * from my_partitioned_table partition for (to_date('20150801', 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

Which would select data from the partition housing that particular date (assuming your partitioning by date).  This is particularly useful in interval partitioning, where Oracle assigns partition names like SYS_xxxx which seem arbitrary at best.

If you'd like to drop partitions older than a given date, its a bit more tricky.  The above syntax is for selecting data, not DDL (alter table).  To do that, you could do something like this (loosely tested):

Create a function to identify which partitions hold data with dates less than a given reference date:

```
create or replace function fn_partition_is_earlier(i_part_tab_name varchar2, i_partition_position number, i_ref_date in date)
return number
is
    l_date_str varchar2(2000);
    l_date date;
begin
    execute immediate 'select high_value from all_tab_partitions where table_name = :tab and partition_position = :pos'
        into l_date_str
        using i_part_tab_name, i_partition_position;

    execute immediate 'select ' || l_date_str || ' from dual' into l_date;
    if (l_date < i_ref_date) then
        return 1;
    end if;
    return 0;
end;
```

Use the function as follows:

```
with part_name as (
    select partition_name
    from (
    select fn_partition_is_earlier(p.table_name, p.partition_position, to_date('20130501', 'YYYYMMDD')) should_drop_flag, p.*
    from all_tab_partitions p
    where table_name = 'MY_TAB'
    )
    where should_drop_flag = 1
)
select 'alter table MY_TAB drop partition ' || part_name.partition_name || ' update global indexes;'
from part_name;
```

The output would give you the script you'd have the DBAs run off hours.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello what I am trying to accomplish is to actually drop partitions older than a specific date... would it be possible with your statement?