# Strings with TO_DATE command as value on the database

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, to-date

I have a problem and I can't solve it yet. On my database I have the string:

```
TO_DATE(' 2015-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN').
```

So when I'm building my query it is like the following:

```
Select my_field FROM my_table.
```

the result is:

```
TO_DATE(' 2015-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
```

Get it?

How to I extract the value of this field as a command statement on a select query?

Comment: What value are you trying to extract from this string?  Are you trying to return, say, just the string "2015-05-01 00:00:00"?  Or are you trying to parse the call to see what parameters are being passed to "to_date"?  What algorithm do you want to use (everything between the first and the second single quote character, for example?)

Comment: Thanks Justin, I'm trying to return the string "2015-05-01 00:00:00".

Comment: What algorithm do you want to use?  Do you want to return everything between the first and the second single quote, for example?  Everything between position 11 (if my counting is right) and 29?  You've provided one example of a string that you have that you want to parse but we don't know anything about the variability of your data.

Comment: Thanks again! I want the get the date from that string. So I have this on the db "TO_DATE(' 2015-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')" and I want just '01-MAR-15'. Because when I run my select, it is resulting me the whole string. It is not parsing the TO_DATE statement.

Comment: The concept you need to use is called dynamic sql.  A google search on "oracle dynamic sql" will enable you to familiarize yourself with the concept.  The next step would be to try some simple examples and then work your way up to your specific situation.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you. I was/am already trying your suggestion. But actually I couldnt solve it yet. But again, thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm confused.  You initially said that you want to return the string "2015-05-01 00:00:00".  Then you say that you want to return a `date` that this string represents.  Do you really want to evaluate whatever expression is stored in that table?  Where the table can contain literally any select-able expression?  Or just `to_date` calls with different values?  Do you need to use SQL or can you use PL/SQL instead?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm making confusion here. I saw the point where I canfused all the question. I have a "TO_DATE..." stored. I just want to get by select query the value of the TO_DATE.  Is stored: "TO_DATE(' 2015-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')" And I want just "01-MAR-15". In other words, I want the result of the statement TO_DATE stored on the db. I can use PL/SQL. Thank you.

Comment: Is the expression that is stored in your table always a `to_date`?  Is it always an expression that evaluates to a `date`?  Or do you want to evaluate whatever expression is stored in that table and this `to_date` is just one example of the sort of expressions that you need to evaluate?  Are you certain that you understand the security implications of dynamically executing SQL (SQL injection for example)?

Comment: Hi Justin, on this column it is always a TO_DATE value. Yes, it will always be a date but on that format. About the security, just to get this information from this table, could it be unsafely in any case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the sqlplus command line, if your system supports the NLS setting:

```
select TO_DATE(' 2015-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') from dual;
```

The value of that field is the whole statement:

```
TO_DATE(' 2015-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
```

I assume you want the actual date to print:

```
DECLARE
  foo varchar2(20):=NULL;
BEGIN
  select my_field 
  into foo 
  from my_table;
  execute immediate my_field;
END;
/
```

Tis is very cunbersome - what you really want is just the date string.  But.  This is what you asked for I think.

Something like this:

```
select substr(myfield, 10, 9) from my_table;
```

This is my take on it.

Comment: Yeah... Jim, as you did it will works. But the value is in the table. I will update de question to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. I was searching for Dynamic SQL and I made the right plsql to get the result.

As the table could have more then one result I used a CURSOR to make a type. (`TYPE tpT IS REF CURSOR; cCursor  tpT;`)  Then I made my query (vSQL) and run it with `OPEN cCursor FOR vSQL`; then I did a Loop to any of the instances of the result. So inside the LOOP I did a `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || AUX || ' FROM DUAL' INTO DATE_AUX`, when `AUX` have the string `TO_DATE(' 2015-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN').`. Then the var `DATE_AUX` has the value `'01-MAR-15'`.

Thank you for all the help. Thanks @justin-cave, @jim-mcnamara and @dan-bracuk for your time. And I'm sorry for the mess of information.